# Spring Cloud Hystrix Dashboard not working with OAuth

Tags: spring, spring-security, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud, hystrix

I am trying to run a simple Spring app with Hystrix Dashboard. I have also enabled Spring security on this app, as the hystrix.streams I want to monitor are security enabled. 
When I access the dashboard url, I get redirected to a login page as expected to get my token, and then after login, I see the dashboard page. I then paste in the url of a hystrix.stream that I wish to monitor and press monitor, however, the next page simply has "Loading..." for both Circuit and Thread pools. I am running this in a PCF environment :
[image]
I can see in the Gradle Dependencies for the project that the version of Hystrix that Spring Cloud Starter is including is 1.4.0-RC6. I download the war for hystrix-dashboard 1.4.0-RC6 from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-dashboard/1.4.0-RC6), and ran that, and noticed that even though I pasted in a correct token in the Authorization window, the effect was the same as the Spring Cloud Hystrix Dashboard - stuck in "Loading..." 
When I ran hystrix-dashboard wars versions 1.4.3 and higher, there was no issue.
Perhaps the version of hystrix in Spring Cloud Hystrix needs to be updated?

Comment: It has been updated to 1.4.1 in snapshots already.  Running against the netflix built wars is something we have not tested.

Comment: Ah, ok. When I build the hystrix-dashboard from source (https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix), the built version is 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT. It looks like the latest official release is 1.4.4 : https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. Accessing the hystrix.stream by pasting the OAuth token in Authorization window definitely does not work on my setup for 1.4.2 or earlier, but does work for 1.4.3 and higher. Hopefully Spring Cloud Hystrix will be updated to 1.4.3 or higher in the near future?

Comment: Here is the issue for upgrading to 1.4.4.  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/300

Comment: 1.4.4 is now in snapshots

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response and action.

I modified the version of spring-cloud-starter-hystrix and spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard in the build.gradle for my project from 1.0.0.RELEASE to 1.0.1.BUILD_SNAPSHOT, but unfortunately choosing Gradle->Refresh Dependencies did not pull down the expected new dependencies. (I deleted %USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.cloud , changed back to 1.0.0.RELEASE and refreshed dependencies to be sure it does work for that version, and it did indeed pull down the dependencies again).

Comment: I also downloaded the source from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/archive/master.zip , and built 1.0.1.BUILD_SNAPSHOT libs on the command line, with "mvn install -s .settings.xml", as instructed on https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/tree/master.
This did make the dependencies available in STS, and the project builds ok, but it fails to run (either on PCF or as a Spring Boot app). I get the following as the first error when I try to run it as a Spring Boot app :

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.archaius.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List org.springframework.cloud.netflix.archaius.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration.externalConfigurations; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'configurableEnvironmentConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/archaius/ArchaiusAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.archaius.ConfigurableEnvironmentConfiguration]:

Comment: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.archaius.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'configurableEnvironmentConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/config/DeploymentContext$ContextKey

Comment: maybe post the stack trace as a gist rather than comments?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying - had to leave work to meet the family. Full stacktrace is [here](https://gist.github.com/cianmac/c6b1ec0e39136b21079b). When I was building against version 1.0.0.RELEASE, the dependency path was : org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard. After building the 1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT source, I notice the dependency path is now org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard, so I updated the project build.gradle accordingly.

Comment: For gradle we recommend using https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin as the gradle policies for resolving dependencies can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

For gradle we recommend using dependency-management-plugin as the gradle policies for resolving dependencies can cause problems.

Comment: Just copied Spencer's comment as an answer to make it easier to find.

Comment: Thanks, I added dependency-management-plugin to the project's build.gradle file, but am still seeing that circular dependency error when I try to run as a Spring boot app. build.gradle and Spring Boot stacktrace available as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/cianmac/c72565e1f71d6f2cbe95)

Comment: What version of archaius-core do you get from `gradle dependencies`?

Comment: archaius-core-0.4.1.jar

Comment: Should be 0.6.5. You need to use the dependency management plugin, not just install it I think. Add `spring-cloud-starter-parent` as a BOM.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that now pulls in 0.6.5, and the app runs successfully as a Spring Boot app. Unfortunately though, it is still not able to access the OAuth2-secured hystrix.stream. Like before , it has "Loading..." for both Circuit and Thread pools. I'll remove security from the app I'm trying to monitor, to see if that's the issue.

Comment: You mean the JavaScript client can't contact the /hystrix.stream? Hardly surprising if you didn't modify it.

Comment: If I paste the hystrix.stream url into a browser window, I get redirected to a uaa login server, and after login, the live stream is displayed. Not sure what you mean by not modifying it?

Comment: OK so your browser can see it now. Does the dashboard start to work once the user is authenticated?

Comment: I was always able to see the stream directly with the browser. The dashboard, which is also security enabled and requires the same login to access, does not work. Using the Netflix Hystrix dashboard directly, (which has a window where you can paste the OAuth2 token), works for release 1.4.3 and above. I've added the Spring Boot stacktrace [here](https://gist.github.com/cianmac/061d693b65187cfa22b3), which shows that the app does have the OAuth token. Perhaps it's not adding it as a header when it tries to access the hystrix.stream?

Comment: The dashboard gets the stream through a proxy. I think we added that. Open an issue in Github?

Comment: I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-starters/issues/18). If you need any more debug info, can upload that no problem. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Issue moved to [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/309)